# Python: Extra comma on csv.Dictreader column

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv, reader

I have this read function where it reads a csv file using csv.DictReader. The file.csv is separated by commas and it fully reads. However, this part of my file has a column that contains multiple commas. My question is, how can I make sure that comma is counted as part of a column? I cannot alter my csv file to meet the criteria.

**Text File**:

```
ID,Name,University,Street,ZipCode,Country
12,Jon Snow,U of Winterfell,Winterfell #45,60434,Westeros
13,Steve Rogers,NYU,108, Chelsea St.,23333,United States
20,Peter Parker,Yale,34, Tribeca,32444,United States
34,Tyrion Lannister,U of Casterly Rock,Kings Landing #89, 43543,Westeros
```

**The desired output is this:**

```
{'ID': '12', 'Name': 'Jon Snow', 'University': 'U of Winterfell', 'Street': 'Winterfell #45', 'ZipCode': '60434', 'Country': 'Westeros'}
{'ID': '13', 'Name': 'Steve Rogers', 'University': 'NYU', 'Street': '108, Chelsea St.', 'ZipCode': '23333', 'Country': 'United States'}
{'ID': '20', 'Name': 'Peter Parker', 'University': 'Yale', 'Street': '34, Tribeca', 'ZipCode': '32444', 'Country': 'United States'}
{'ID': '34', 'Name': 'Tyrion Lannister', 'University': 'U of Casterly Rock', 'Street': 'Kings Landing #89', 'ZipCode': '43543', 'Country': 'Westeros'}
```

As you can tell the 'Street' has at least two commas due to the numbers:

13,Steve Rogers,NYU,**108, Chelsea St.**,23333,United States

20,Peter Parker,Yale,**34, Tribeca**,32444,United States

**Note:** Most of the columns being read splits by a **str,str** BUT under the 'Street' column it is followed by a **str, str** (there is an extra space after the comma). I hope this makes sense.

The options I tried looking out is using re.split, but I don't know how to implement it on my read file. I was thinking `re.split(r'(?!\s),(?!\s)',x[:-1])`? How can I make sure the format from my file will count as part of any column? I can't use pandas.

My current output looks like this right now:

```
{'ID': '12', 'Name': 'Jon Snow', 'University': 'U of Winterfell', 'Street': 'Winterfell #45', 'ZipCode': '60434', 'Country': 'Westeros'}
{'ID': '13', 'Name': 'Steve Rogers', 'University': 'NYU', 'Street': '108', 'ZipCode': 'Chelsea St.', 'Country': '23333', None: ['United States']}
{'ID': '20', 'Name': 'Peter Parker', 'University': 'Yale', 'Street': '34', 'ZipCode': 'Tribeca', 'Country': '32444', None: ['United States']}
{'ID': '34', 'Name': 'Tyrion Lannister', 'University': 'U of Casterly Rock', 'Street': 'Kings Landing #89', 'ZipCode': '43543', 'Country': 'Westeros'}
```

This is my read function:

```
import csv

list = []
with open('file.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
  csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=",", skipinitialspace=True)

  for col in csv_reader:
    list.append(dict(col))
    print(dict(col))
```

Comment: It's not possible to solve this with any CSV library. How is it supposed to know which commas are separators and which are part of the value of a field?

Comment: If a field contains a comma, it has to be put in quotes.

Comment: @Barmar is there a way to do it with csv.reader? or is that different?

Comment: @Barmar can i implement my re.split example onto my reading function?

Comment: If it's never the case that a real field can begin with space, I guess so. What happened when you tried?

Comment: @Barmar I get this:  "split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"
I'm not sure how to really implement it in my code.

Comment: You're not calling `re.split()` on the line you read from the file. Are you trying to use that with `DictReader`? This is *instead* of using the `csv` module.

Comment: @Barmar yes I'm trying to use it with Dictreader under my read function. Do you mind showing me how I can't implement what you're trying to say? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `csv` if the file isn't valid CSV format.

You need to call `re.split()` on ordinary lines, not on dictionaries.

```
list = []
with open('file.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    keys = csv_file.readline().strip().split(',') # Read header line
    for line in csv_file:
        line = line.strip()
        row = re.split(r'(?!\s),(?!\s)',line)
        list.append(dict(zip(keys, row)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution for the problem is modifying the script that generates the csv file.

If you have a chance to modify that output you can do 2 things

- Use a delimiter other than a comma such as `|` symbol or `;` whatever you believe it doesn't exist in the string.
- Or enclose all columns with `"` so you'll be able to split them by `,` which are actual separators.

If you don't have a chance to modify the output.

And if you are sure about that multiple commas are only in the street column; then you should use `csv.reader` instead of `DictReader` this way you can get the columns by Indexes that you are already sure. for instance `row[0]` will be `ID` `row[1]` will be `Name` and `row[-1]` will be `Country` `row[-2]` will be `ZipCode` so `row[2:-2]` would give you what you need i guess. Indexes can be arranged but the idea is clear I guess.

Hope that helps.

---

Edit:

```
import csv

list = []
with open('file.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",", skipinitialspace=True)
  # pass the header row
  next(csv_reader)
  for row in csv_reader:
  list.append({"ID": row[0],
               "Name": row[1],
               "University": row[2],
               "Street": ' '.join(row[3:-2]),
               "Zipcode": row[-2],
               "Country": row[-1]})
print(list)
```

-- 
Here is the output (with pprint)

```
[{'Country': 'Westeros',
'ID': '12',
'Name': 'Jon Snow',
'Street': 'Winterfell #45',
'University': 'U of Winterfell',
'Zipcode': '60434'},
{'Country': 'United States',
'ID': '13',
'Name': 'Steve Rogers',
'Street': '108 Chelsea St.',
'University': 'NYU',
'Zipcode': '23333'},
 {'Country': 'United States',
'ID': '20',
'Name': 'Peter Parker',
'Street': '34 Tribeca',
'University': 'Yale',
'Zipcode': '32444'},
 {'Country': 'Westeros',
'ID': '34',
'Name': 'Tyrion Lannister',
'Street': 'Kings Landing #89',
'University': 'U of Casterly Rock',
'Zipcode': '43543'}]
```

-- second edit
edited the index on the street.
Regards.

Comment: He clearly stated that he can't change the file format.

Comment: And that leads to the second part to my answer then :)

Comment: @rkirmizi so how will my read function look like after changing it to csv.reader while maintaining in a dictionary format? Because if I were to change it, Dictreader to reader on my code it gives me an error.